# How to correctly quantify the term "research"

Tags: word-choice, quantifiers

What is the correct way to express the quantity of research.

Eg:
Joe has done a lot of research on the subject.

Is there a better way to express "a lot".

Thank you

Comment: Loads, beaucoup, a shit-load, a ton, heaps...

Comment: @HotLicks I'm not sure how many contexts there are in which the phrase "a shit ton" is a **better** way to express "a lot", although I'd agree it's an alternative. Personally, when the time is right for garish / vulgar statement of degree, I prefer "a metric fuckload", but that's a mater of personal taste.

Comment: not a lot, f**k all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Extensive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/extensive)*:

> adjective
>
> 1.0 Covering or affecting a large area:
>
> 1.1 Large in amount or scale:
>
> ODO

*Joe has done **extensive** research on the subject.*

Answer (score 4):

*[Comprehensive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/comprehensive)*:

> > adjective
>
> 1.0 Including or dealing with all or nearly all elements or aspects of something:
>
> 1.1 Of large content or scope; wide-ranging:
>
> ODO

*Joe has done **comprehensive** research on the subject.*

Comprehensive implies more *completeness* than extensive does.

Comment: I think extensive is a better term in my case as I do not want to make the assumption of "all or nearly all elements". Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It might be a mouthful but *[voluminous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/voluminous)* goes well with research:

> adjective
>
> 2 (Of writing) very lengthy and detailed:
>
> ODO

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the amount of time Joe has invested into his research. "Joe has done many hours of research . . ."

If the reader will be aware of the amount of time above which it can now be considered "a lot," then you can be more specific. "Joe has done hundreds of hours of research." If Joe were eleven years old and was doing a book report, the reader surely surmises that hundreds of hours is overkill and Joe was thorough. If Joe were a scientist working on a cure for cancer, suddenly hundreds of hours doesn't seem like a lot.

Comment: This is the only answer so far mentioning accurate quantification.